# How can I log an HTML element as a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-closure-library, developer-tools

Using Google Chrome, if you `console.log` an object, it lets you inspect the element in the console. For example:

```
var a = { "foo" : "bar", "whiz" : "bang" };
console.log(a);
```

This prints out `Object` which can be inspected by clicking on arrows next to it. If however I try to log an HTMLElement:

```
var b = goog.dom.query('html')[0];
console.log(b);
```

This prints out `<html></html>` which can not be inspected by clicking on arrows next to it. If I want to see the JavaScript object (with its methods and fields) instead of just the DOM of the element, how would I do that?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Use `console.dir`:

```
var element = document.documentElement; // or any other element
console.log(element); // logs the expandable <html>…</html>
console.dir(element); // logs the element’s properties and values
```

If you’re inside the console already, you could simply type `dir` instead of `console.dir`:

```
dir(element); // logs the element’s properties and values
```

To simply list the different property names (without the values), you could use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(element); // logs the element’s property names
```

Even though there’s no public `console.keys()` method, if you’re inside the console already, you could just enter:

```
keys(element); // logs the element’s property names
```

This won’t work outside the console window, though.

Comment: When I use console.dir() directly in the console, it works.  But if I write it in my actual .js file in VS Code, the chrome dev console just logs the name of the file that it was written in and the line number.  Do happen to know why?

Answer (score 37):

try this:

```
console.dir(element)
```

**Reference**
[[Video] Paul Irish on becoming a console power user.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mf_yNLlgic)

Comment: +1 I was always using `[[element]]` to create an array so that Chrome was forced to display it as an object... Thanks!

Comment: Great straightforward answer. By 'oldest' sort came in a hair after the other one, hence the accept, but many thanks!

Comment: No problems. I don't mind which is accepted, but accepted answer should be the one most helpful to others later.

Answer (score 10):

Browser print only HTML part, you can put the element in a object to see DOM structure.

```js
console.log({element})
```

Comment: This was what I need, thanks! For the record, the output looks like:
`document: document,  location: Location {ancestorOrigins: (..)`

Comment: Good to know it, hope you gain more by it