# How do you access the element HTML from within an Angular attribute directive?

Tags: angular

The Angular docs provide an example for creating an attribute directive that changes the background color of an element:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

```html
<p myHighlight>Highlight me!</p>
```

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Can I also use `el.nativeElement` to get the content of the element (e.g. `Highlight me!`), modify this and update the element?

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log(el.nativeElement)` and tried to inspect this object?

Comment: yes, I get this: `<h2 _ngcontent-cul-1="" typedeffect="">My Heroes</h2>`
but I've not had any joy in accessing the content

Comment: didn't expect that, im sorry. i posted an answer including this "issue".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So actually, my comment that you should do a `console.log(el.nativeElement)` should have pointed you in the right direction, but I didn't expect the output to be just a string representing the `DOM Element`.

What you have to do to inspect it in the way it helps you with your problem, is to do a `console.log(el)` in your example, then you'll have access to the `nativeElement` object and will see a property called `innerHTML`.

Which will lead to the answer to your original question:

```
let myCurrentContent:string = el.nativeElement.innerHTML; // get the content of your element
el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 'my new content'; // set content of your element
```

---

### **Update for better approach:**

Since it's the accepted answer and web workers are getting more important day to day (and it's considered best practice anyway) I want to add this suggestion by Mark Rajcok here.

The best way to manipulate `DOM Elements` programmatically is using the [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html):

```
constructor(private _elemRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) { 
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elemRef.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'my new content');
}
```

### Edit

Since `Renderer` is deprecated now, use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) instead with `setProperty`

---

### Update:

[This question with its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633835/how-can-i-log-an-html-element-as-a-javascript-object) explained the `console.log` behavior.

Which means that **`console.dir(el.nativeElement)`** would be the more direct way of accessing the `DOM Element` as an "inspectable" Object in your console for this situation.

---

Hope this helped.

Comment: The renderer add the 'my new content' to the existing content and not replacing it.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it would probably be wise to also beware that XSS vulnerabilities could be a concern for some users. I think I'll be combining the above approach with this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467000/sanitize-input-in-angular2

Comment: You're right, but the question is not about dynamically including html or css, so i don't see why i should explain it here (the topic is pretty deep and like you said you'll find other sources about it).

Comment: Renderer2 ? Who the hell is developing this framework ? I was expecting more of the angular team ...

Comment: innerHtml does not work but innerText work. why?

Answer (score 14):

I suggest using [Render](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html), as the [ElementRef API doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html#!#nativeElement-anchor) suggests:

> ... take a look at Renderer which provides API that can safely be used even when direct access to native elements is not supported.
>   Relying on direct DOM access creates *tight coupling between your application and rendering layers* which will make it *impossible to separate the two and deploy your application into a web worker or Universal*.

*Always* use the **Renderer** for it will make you code (or library you right) be able to work when using Universal or WebWorkers.

```ts
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        renderer.setElementProperty(el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'some new value');
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like Render has a getElementProperty() method though, so I guess we still need to use NativeElement for that part. Or (better) pass the content in as an input property to the directive.

Answer (score 9):

This is because the content of

```
<p myHighlight>Highlight me!</p>
```

has not been rendered when the constructor of the HighlightDirective is called so there is no content yet.

If you implement the [AfterContentInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#aftercontent) hook you will get the element and its content.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })

export class HighlightDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        //el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(){
        //you can get to the element content here 
        //this.el.nativeElement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on @Mark answer, I add the constructor to directive and it work with me.

I share a sample to whom concern.

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
}
```

TS file

```
@Directive({ selector: '[accordion]' })
export class AccordionDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event) {
    console.info($event);

    this.el.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-open');

    var content = this.el.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      // accordion is currently open, so close it
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      // accordion is currently closed, so open it
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";

    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<button accordion class="accordion">Accordian #1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo,
        ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
      </p>     
    </div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-accordion?file=src/app/app.component.ts