# One click handler for multiple elements in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-directives

Let's say we have a div with 3 links inside.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="link">link1</a>
    <a class="link">link2</a>
    <a class="link">link3</a>
</div>
```

In order to assign a click handler for the links in jQuery we can do smth like this: 
`$('.wrap a').on('click', callback);`.

What is the best approach for that in Angular2?

From what I learned I could use a simple (click) for each link, like:
`<a class="link" (click)="callback()">`, but to me it looks odd.
Another option would be to use a directive and do smth like
 `<a class="link" [directive]="value">`, this one I like more.

Is there an even better implementation of described case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event will bubble up to the parent div so you could put a the event handler there.

```
  <div class="wrap" (click)="clicked($event)">
      <a id="link1" class="link">link1</a>
      <a id="link2" class="link">link2</a>
      <a id="link3" class="link">link3</a>
  </div>
```

```js
  export class AppComponent {

    clicked(event: MouseEvent) {
      console.log(event.srcElement.id);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it depends on what you would like to do. But if you just want to assign a clickHandler you normaly go with the (click) directive. Why does this looks odd to you?

If you would like to access the ClickEvent within you handler pass the `$event` paramter to your callback like so: `<a class="link" (click)="callback($event)">link</a>`

if you have a collection of links you can iterate over it:

`public links = ['link1','link2','link3']`;

then in your template:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a class="link" *ngFor="let link of links">{{link}}</a>
</div>
```

If you just want to navigate within your singlePageApplication you usually just use the `routerLink` directive.

```
<a routerLink="/my-path">link1</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div (click)="onClick($event)">
        <a id="link1" href="#" class="link">link1</a>
        <a id="link2" href="#" class="link">link2</a>
        <a id="link3" href="#" class="link">link3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
  }
  onClick(event) {
      alert(event.srcElement.id);
  }
}
```

Working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/78JtCJn2fPbjPYSeluVn)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way for this is to use directive and maybe parse the inner HTML to compose a valid link as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002640/how-do-you-access-the-element-html-from-within-an-angular-2-attribute-directive)