# Can @HostListener return HTML element?

Tags: html, angular

Before creating a new directive, I had this `<input #inputBox (click)="getElement(inputBox )" element-directive/>` to get the `inputBox` element.

Now I have moved everything to a directive and I am stuck on how can I get the `inputBox` element into

input.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[element-directive]'
})
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
public onClick($event) {
    console.dir($event); // mouse click event, not html element
}
```

Can @HostListener access to/return HTML element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the element HTML from within an Angular 2 attribute directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002640/how-do-you-access-the-element-html-from-within-an-angular-2-attribute-directive)

Comment: You can try $event.target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look [here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#write-the-directive-code)

you can inject ElementRef in your directive constructor to access the native HTML element :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[element-directive]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    private myDomEl;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       this.myDomEl = el.nativeElement;         // <= native HTML INPUT element in your example, then use in on click event
    }
}
```

you dont need to use @HostLinstener for that