# VueJs - How to access DOM property of an element from $refs

Tags: dom, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an element

```
<tbody ref="tbody">
  <tr class="row" :ref="userIndex" v-for="(userData, uid, userIndex) in users" :key="uid">
```

in my template. I need to access/edit the DOM property like scrollTop, verticalOffset of `<tr>` element. How can I achieve this?

I have tried to access using `this.$refs[userIndex][0].$el` but its not working. I can see all the properties in the console but I am unable to access them. However `this.$refs.tbody.scrollTop` works.

Below is the snap showing `console.log(this.$refs)`[image]

`console.log(this.$refs[userIndex])`
[image]

`console.log(this.$refs[userIndex][0])`
[image]

As you can see when I use `this.$refs[userIndex][0]` I don't see the DOM properties

Answer (score 4):

A `$ref` object will only have a `$el` property if it is a Vue component.  If you add a `ref` attribute to a regular element, the `$ref` will a reference to that DOM Element.

Simply reference `this.$refs[userIndex][0]` instead of `this.$refs[userIndex][0].$el`.

To see the properties of that element in the console, you'll need to use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633835/how-can-i-log-an-html-element-as-a-javascript-object)

But, you can access properties of the element like you would any other object. So, you could log the `scrollTop`, for instance, via `console.log(this.$refs[userIndex][0].scrollTop)`.

Comment: @nbbk Use console.dir if you want to see the element's properties

Comment: It's also worth highlighting that `this.$refs.refName` is always an array. Even if you expect your ref to be a single element, it'll still be in an array. I missed that part and it left me staring at my code for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `verticalOffset` exists. `offsetTop` does. To console log an Dom element and its property, use `console.dir`

Open the browser console and run this working snippet:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: {
      first: {
        name: "Louise"
      },
      second: {
        name: "Michelle"
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.dir(this.$refs[1][0])
    console.log('property: ', this.$refs[1][0].offsetTop)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<table><tbody ref="tbody">
  <tr :ref="userIndex" v-for="(userData, uid, userIndex) in users" :key="uid">
  <td>{{userData}}: {{userIndex}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad. I was checking with verticalOffset.