# Display HTMLInputElement in console of chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the HTMLInputElement object of an HTML input :

```
 <div>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="toto" value="test" />
</div>
```

JS script :

```
<script>
  const inputEl = document.getElementById("name"); 
  console.log(inputEl);
</script>
```

In the chrome console, I get this :

[image]

But I want to display it as an HTMLInputElement object.

In stackblitz console I get the object :

[image]

Thank you :)

But locally I dont get the object !!

Comment: use console.table

Comment: can you tell us more explanation? what is htmlobject you need? what is your expectation.?

Comment: Display with console.table is not intuitive for debugging the object :(

Comment: Logically the browser should display an object which contains all the attributes..etc, at the top it's just a basic example ,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log an HTML element as a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633835/how-can-i-log-an-html-element-as-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What output are you expecting and Where do you want it?

Comment: In the stackblitz i got the object , but locally no :( see the screenshot  in the top , i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean by 'display as an HTMLInputElement'.
If you want to see all its fields, you might want to use `console.dir(inputEl)`.

Comment: Because in HTML, they say that any tag turns into an HTMLInputElement object, The HTMLInputElement interface provides special properties and methods for manipulating the options, layout, and presentation of <input> elements.

Comment: In the stackblitz i got the object , but locally no :( see the screenshot  in the top , i updated my question

Comment: @abadou What's happening is that `console.log()` uses `toString()`, which returns a custom string like the one in your first screenshot. If you use `console.dir()`, it evaluates the actual keys the object has and prints them, similar to the second screenshot.