# I have a variable in JavaScript and I want to assign that variable value to asp label control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label, variable-assignment, var

This is my JavaScript

```
if (response.authResponse) {
    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook        
    var user_email = response.authResponse.id;

    FB.api('/me', function (me) {
        if (me.name) {
            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
        }
    });
}
```

Here I want to assign `var user_email` to asp label control. How should I do?

Comment: Can you post more code of the page? What asp label you talking about?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblfbid" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249542/how-to-assign-a-text-to-label-in-javascript

Comment: You can access `user_email ` , you can assign it too

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ClientID` property to get client-side element:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblfbid" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
...
<script>
...
if (response.authResponse) {
    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook        
    var user_email = response.authResponse.id;

    FB.api('/me', function (me) {
        if (me.name) {
            // Just for client-side
            document.getElementById('<%=lblfbid.ClientID %>').innerHTML = user_email;
            // Send user_email on server-side ($.post is from jQuery) for some reason: 
            $.post(
              '/MyService.asmx/SendUserEmail', 
              { userEmail: user_email }, 
              function() { /* do something on success */ });
        }
    });
}
...
</script>
```

And `MyService.asmx.cs`:

```
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void SendUserEmail(userEmail userEmail)
    {
       // do some stuff with userEmail
    }
}
```

Comment: feeeper... Thank you... I was not getting that syntax. I'll try this one.

Comment: but i did not get that how it is going to assign 'var user_email' value to that label. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: @Prady Do you mean something like `document.getElementById('<%=lblfbid.ClientID %>').innerHTML = user_email;` ?

Comment: @Prady Sure, you can

Comment: Why I asked this... because I want to assign that user_email variable's value to lblfbid.

Comment: I am not getting any error. The problem is I am logging in to my application with facebook. And I want to display that name or email on page next to login page. but it is redirecting on login page only.

Comment: hence i am trying to assign that variable to asp control so that I can access it on my .cs page

Comment: @Prady It's impossible do that that way. You have to send your `user_email` to the server via AJAX (create some asmx service and call it) or call `__doPostback` (AJAX imho more suitable)

Comment: ohhhh... mmm... ok... i'll try

Comment: can I take that value in session? and can i use that session on my cs page?

Comment: @Prady If you save `user_email` into the session then you can get it from session.

Comment: from aspx page to cs page? Is it possible?

Comment: @Prady Nope. You can save `user_email` to the Session in the *.asmx and then use `user_email` from there.